# Can z-index be used for buttons in front of pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

Using CSS I have tried to make z-index a solution for putting a few buttons in front of my main picture (which is also my user picture), and it is not working! I have tried fixing it for a while, here is the code -->
**This code is used considering chrome browser with 100%, full page**

```js
//As you may see below, I have attempten wrapping the picture in a div, and in css I have tried adding position relative. It doesn't work though!
```

```css
button {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#background-image-Menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#background-image-Menu #bim {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-image-Menu">
  <img src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/-LEZqqfbyUAC2c8P35J8f4vIRxFBXD8CG9lFBztPYwzdYoa6EPEyh7X0uNn39MwEjh02Og=s142" id="bim" />
</div>
<button id="start_engine">Create new game</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="load_game">Load game</button>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not setting the background image directly on the #background-image-Menu div itself?

Comment: Your z-index looks fine however you did not set any kind of positioning for your buttons (top, left, bottom, right).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` only controls the stacking order. Your elements are still laid out in the usual linear fashion.

If you want them to occupy the same x and y co-ordinates, you will need to move one of the elements to the position of the other one. You could do this with negative margins, setting `top` or a couple of other techniques.

That said, it looks like your actual goal is to have a background image. Your image doesn't appear to be conveying any information (and has no `alt` attribute) so it, presumably, isn't a content image.

```css
#menu {
  background: url('https://lh6.ggpht.com/-LEZqqfbyUAC2c8P35J8f4vIRxFBXD8CG9lFBztPYwzdYoa6EPEyh7X0uNn39MwEjh02Og=s142') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<button id="start_engine">Create new game</button>
<button id="load_game">Load game</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point about whether the image is a "background" or "content" image

Comment: Thanks! But 1 problem, when I use notepad++ (didn't test it on anything else) it doesn't extend to the full height, even when I use height 100%, but I'm assuming that's what the background-size was for, but its not working?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Because they are all positioned as relative, they will not be place on top of the image. Either the buttons need to be set as `position: absolute;` or the image should. Realistically, you would want your image to be positioned absolute to achieve what you're trying to do.

Here's what it looks like when you give the image an absolute position: http://jsfiddle.net/w1gjufys/

---

Alternatively, you can also position your buttons using `top: -100px;` where the "-100px" value could be changed to whatever you'd like it to be. Respectively, you'd use `left: 100px;` to move it horizontally. This is what it would look like using this method: http://jsfiddle.net/w1gjufys/2/

---

z-index controls the z-axis of things (and kudos to you for applying a position other than static on your elements with z-index). Z-axis would be equivalent to looking at a stack of cards from a birds-eye view where the first card (and only card you would see) would have the highest value in z-index.

---

Keep in mind that you shouldn't use `<br>` tags as a method to space things as that could make your html looking messy. Apply margins instead. Give your buttons a class or ID and target them specifically to control how much of a margin each one should get.

Comment: The second answer was irrevelant, as on this site for the snippet it adds it below, as to where the program I use adds it behind for some reason. 

As for the first answer, it contradicts, in my program that I'm using at least, with that I shouldn't use <br> tags as a method. Using margin only moves the picture, and the picture extends across the page. It's a good answer, if it weren't for the program I'm using.

But I definitely will take some of those things into thought. Thanks very much!